# Float64 in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, avfoundation, cmtime

I'm using CMTime for AVAssets for video clip. To trim the video without saving the new video file I just want to keep track of the start time and the duration.

The CMTimeGetSeconds() method will return a Float64, what would be the best way to store this in CoreData?

I can't use a NSNumber as the float type round the Float64 way to much. 1.200000 is 1.0000 when I create my NSNumber.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-[NSNumber numberWithDouble:]` rounds it too much when you access the `doubleValue` (not `floatValue`)?

Comment: I'm afraid not,

  Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
  self.videoTrack.duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration];
  NSLog(@"First Duration: %f, %f", duration, [self.videoTrack.duration doubleValue]);

prints:
 First Duration: 1.295000, 1.000000

Comment: It is highly likely that that the `videoTrack` adjust the duration to a nice round number that makes since for video playback. Try creating an `NSNumber` and printing it without setting it to the duration propery and you will probably get the exact same result.

Comment: in my core data model file i accidentally made the duration an integer. thanks for pointing that out! Fixed! If you give it as a answer to the question i will mark it as a correct answer.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it is highly likely that that the `videoTrack` object will adjust the duration to a nice round number that makes since for video playback. Try creating an NSNumber and printing it without setting it to the `duration` property and you will probably get the exact same result. Also make sure the data type is set to a `Double` in the CoreData model.